# Solving specificity issues with modifier classes vs multi-class selectors and @layer?

Tags: css

Given the following css/html:

```css
/* from css framework */
.container .card {
    margin: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
.container .card.narrow {
    max-width: 50px;
}
.container .card.wide {
    background-color: purple;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<style>
    .special { background-color: red; }  /* end user trying to override */
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card narrow"></div>
    <div class="card wide special"></div>
</div>
```

The end user override will not have any effect (the second card will remain purple) since `.container .card.wide` has higher specificity.

Most solutions I've seen to this problem have involved "flattening" the css nesting (or making it explicit), leading to rather verbose/repetitive class names.  The `special` class has now the same specificity as `c2-card c2-card-wide` so the second box turns red:

```css
/* from css framework */
.c2-card {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.c2-card-narrow {
  max-width: 50px;
}
.c2-card-wide {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<style>
    .special { background-color: red; }  /* end user trying to override */
</style>
<div class="c2">
    <div class="c2-card c2-card-narrow"></div>
    <div class="c2-card c2-card-wide special"></div>
</div>
```

With `@layers` available in all browsers, is there now any reason to use the above verbose solution instead of simply:

```css
/* from css framework */
@layer theme {
  .container .card {
      margin: 20px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: green;
  }
  .container .card.narrow {
      max-width: 50px;
  }
  .container .card.wide {
      background-color: purple;
      width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
    .special { background-color: red; }  /* end user trying to override */
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card narrow"></div>
    <div class="card wide special"></div>
</div>
```

..which seems to give you short and semantic class names while preserving the ability to override without being super-aware of specificity?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: ‘Is it now preferred?’ seems to be a question which can only be answered by opinions rather than facts. Is there something more in your question which I’ve missed?

Comment: @AHaworth I've changed the wording of the question. What I want to know is if there are any other reasons to use verbose/single-level class names that I'm not aware of?